# Google apps script - concatenate values

Tags: google-apps-script, merge, concatenation

i have to concatenate values (not strings). I searched in the documentation but only found a solution for strings:
You can use the operator += or the concat() function.

Thats the table i work with:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNpdd.jpg)

Here is my script:

```
function getDatabaseAsObjectArray() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const headers = values[0];
  const databaseAsObjectArray = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    const entry = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      const key = headers[j];
      if (key === '') continue;
      entry[key] = values[i][j];
    }

    var number_1 = 5
    var number_2 = 5
    entry['value_4'] = number_1 += number_2
    
    databaseAsObjectArray.push(entry);
    console.log(entry);
  }
}
```

the result should be "value_4 = 55", the outcome is:
{ id: 1, value_1: 2, value_2: 3, value_3: 4, value_4: 10 }

Answer (score 0):

Use the `toString()` method of `Number`.

```
let number_1 = 5;
let number_2 = 5;
entry['value_4'] = number_1.toString() + number_2.toString();
```

To convert the concatinated string to a number use `Number()`

```
entry['value_4'] = Number(number_1.toString() + number_2.toString());
```

Results

```
5:57:29 AM  Notice  Execution started
5:57:30 AM  Info    [ { id: 1, value_1: 2, value_2: 3, value_3: 4, value_4: '55' },
  { id: 2, value_1: 5, value_2: 6, value_3: 7, value_4: '55' },
  { id: 3, value_1: 8, value_2: 9, value_3: 10, value_4: '55' } ]
5:57:30 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Number()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)

Comment: you created a string. It works but the "value" can´t be used for further calculations.

Comment: You didn't say that in your question